# Keeping SwiftLint executable under source control

Tags: xcode, git, swiftlint

Is it a good practice to copy the SwiftLint executable to the project folder (under `/support` or something) and push it to git repo?

Reason for this is that developers don't have to manually download and install SwiftLint in all computers and every developer will consistently use the same version of the executable.

Are there are drawbacks of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my self:

As mentioned in the SwiftLint git readme file, Installing it via Cocoapods is the recommended way.